# UDP Server : Broadcast names of all files present in my directory

Tags: java, udp, client-server, broadcast

I would like to periodically broadcast the names of all the file available in my directory. What is wrong with my program? Running the program gives the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:183)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:832)
at UDPServer.main(UDPServer.java:42)
```

Here is the Server code :

```
public class UDPServer
{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
  {
    try (DatagramChannel channel =
            DatagramChannel.open())
            {
                InetSocketAddress local = new InetSocketAddress(0);
                channel.socket().bind(local);
                InetSocketAddress broadcast = new InetSocketAddress("255.255.255.255",5959);
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);
                while(true)
                {
                    //channel.connect(broadcast);
                    int n=buffer.position()/2;
                    //buffer.flip();
                    buffer.rewind();
                    String fileName = new String();
                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                        fileName += buffer.getChar();
                    DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(fileName));
                    for(Path p : stream)
                    {
                        buffer.put(p.toString().getBytes());
                        buffer.flip();
                        channel.send(buffer, broadcast);
                        buffer.clear();
                    }
                 }
            }
   }
}
```

UPDATE 1 :

I have changed the first `buffer.flip()` to `buffer.rewind()`. This removed the `BufferOverflowException`. Next I got an `IllegalStateException: connect already invoked`. So I removed `channel.connect(broadcast)`. Finally I get `file.FileSystemException` caused by `IOException: Too many open files`. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you said **HOW** this isn't working.

Comment: Hello @MarcB: . I have added the error that I am getting.

Comment: did you actually READ the error message? you overflowed your buffer